# Retriving content of the elements in a XML string

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

I'm just trying to load a one element xml string to a DOMDocument object, and then retrieve the content but i can't..This is what I'm trying:

```
$xml = '<element_1>foobar</element_1>';

$dd = new DOMDocument();
$dd->loadXml($xml);

var_dump($dd->getElementsByTagName('element_1')); //this prints object(DOMNodeList)#2 (0) {
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Since it prints `object(DOMNodeList)`, did you maybe take a look at the docs for [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)? Note that the method you called is called getElement **s** ByTagName(), and as such it returns a collection of zero or more elements. You need to separate out the element(s) you want and get the *value* of the node (guess what that property is called).

Comment: "but i can't" is not an error message nor a problem description. After 400+ questions you should know how to ask a question imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using **simplexml_load_string()**?

Example:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<element_1>
foobar
</element_1>
XML;

$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo $data;
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Answer (score 1):

Your missing `item(int)` and the `nodeValue` of that item

```
$xml = '<element_1>foobar</element_1>';

$dd = new DOMDocument();
$dd->loadXml($xml);

var_dump($dd->getElementsByTagName('element_1')->item(0)->nodeValue);
//string 'foobar' (length=6)
```